# Change the PHP version with CRON (on GoDaddy shared server)?

Tags: php, cron, version, cpanel, cron-task

I have GoDaddy shared business hosting and have 15 sites running on it, all created in the latest version of Joomla. Most of the time, everything runs well and resource usage is barely anything with a max usage of around 10%.

Occasionally (randomly), from once per day to once per week, all of a sudden all of my sites will go down. If i catch it quickly as soon as there is an issue, I can sometimes access my cPanel and change my PHP version down to 5.6 and immediately right back to 7.1... This appears to essentially restart the services and everything returns to normal (poor mans reboot). However, often I cannot even access my cpanel and in that case I have to call GoDaddy support for them to restart the services manually to resolve the issue.

Over time, this has become a real pain in the butt and is especially an issue when I am sleeping, because the sites can be down all night and I don't know until I get up and check everything.

Therefore, is there a way to change the cPanel version of PHP using a CRON task once or twice per day? Either by just running a command, or, with a special PHP file that is triggered?

I have searched all morning and can not find where anyone else is talking about this.

Comment: I would suggest you check out the server logs and see if you can identify the problem there. Restarting the server periodically is not really a permanent solution.

Comment: While I would love to have a permanent solution for this, the logs do not show anything useful and GoDaddy is unable to explain in any capacity why this is happening. At this point it is either move hosting away from GoDaddy or deal with the issue. That is why I am asking the above question.

Comment: Try that, it should restart your server without changing the version - '/sbin/initctl  restart php5-fpm' and you can make it a cron job

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Can you please clarify that command for a shared hosting environment on GoDaddy? I tried running it but it tells me that there is no such file or directory. Also, if I am using PHP 7.1, should it be "php7.1-fpm" instead?

Comment: @BryanEarl -  Is there any server side error message like 503 - Service Unavailable error or 500 - Internal Server Error error when the 'sites go down'? Just to clear what it means for you that "the site goes down".